# Количество свободного места на 4 Гб еММС после установки Linux

Tags: linux

Всем добрый день. Сразу скажу что с Linux не работал. Сейчас стоит задача подбора оборудования.
 Вопрос в следующем:  есть промышленный компьютер у которого установлено 4 Гб (eMMC) под загрузку ОС и в нем имеется разъем под SDHC флеш. Начальная его задача сбор данных с приборов и передача их по GSM. Но что в дальнейшем на нем придется еще делать неизвестно.
 На рассмотрение берутся вот эти железяки: rBOX610-FL и rBOX630-FL (www.ipc2u.ru)
Вот что на одном из них установленно:
[image: ПО]
Суть вопроса: какие разделы Linux можно перенести из еММС на SDHC и сколько примерно будет свободного места на еММС  для возможной установки других программ?
 Как то после Windows - 4 Гб настораживают, если бы было 8 Гб, то вопроса бы не возникло.
 Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: вопрос абсолютно «ниочём». чтобы как-то привести его в «человеческий» вид, дополните его, пожалуйста, информацией: 1. *какие разделы Linux можно перенести из еММС на SDHC?* — а какие «разделы» есть? 2. *сколько примерно будет свободного места на еММС для возможной установки других программ?* — а сколько есть сейчас?

Comment: 4Gb --- это как-то даже очень много учитывая античность ядра и пр. Даже современные ядра с минимальным окружением занимают 100-150Мб.